# Can you lock out users from editing graphs in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, vba

I have a tool written in VBA in Excel but I am having problems with users changing the graph data series.

Is there anyway that when they open their copy of the file, to deny access to graph controls?  eg, not allow them to edit data series, graph type, etc.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can e.g. set the [ProtectData' property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/office/ff195687.aspx) of the chart to True:

```
Worksheets(1).ChartObjects(1).Chart.ProtectData = True
```

Take a look at this site as well please: [Protecting Charts in Microsoft Excel](http://peltiertech.com/Excel/ChartsHowTo/ChartProtection.html)

Comment: @unknownSPY, don't forget, when you have enough rep, you can +1 as well :)

Comment: @Dave  Yeah, I would have already done but my rep on other SO sites doesn't count towards permissions :(